# Prove $2(x^2 + y^2)$ is the sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Okay so, first time using maths stack exchange (that's why the layout may be off), but I had two questions (both related):

a) How would I prove (by direct argument) that $2(x^2 + y^2)$ is the sum of two squares.

I tried and well all I could reach was the conclusion that $2x^2 + 2y^2 = m^2 + n^2$ (basically I got nowhere).

If you could help with the method of approaching this question it would be very appreciated.

b) If a question is worded as prove or disprove, when do you know when not to disprove,  i.e. I kept attempting to disprove a statement (by counter example) and wasted a lot of time in doing so; is there trick?

I could do most of the other proofs fine but this one, unfortunately,got me stuck.

Thank you :)

Comment: **Hint:** $(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2$.

Comment: b) There is no trick. Try both, switch between them. If you fail to find a counterexample, see if you can figure out _why_ you fail, and try to build a proof around that. If you fail to find a proof, see if you can figure out _which exact step_ stops your proof attempts, and use that to try to construct a counterexample around that.

Comment: Welcome no MSE. Please choose your tags carefully. Each one among the four that you picked is wrong.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neat way to express any multiple  $n(x^2+y^2)$ as a sum of two squares is to first express $n$ as the sum of two squares and then use the identity $$(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=(ax+by)^2+(ay-bx)^2.$$

So, since $2=1^2+1^2$, you are looking for $$(1^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2)=(x+y)^2+(y-x)^2.$$

Comment: That is the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity. Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity

Answer (score 1):

You could write $((\sqrt 2)x)^2 +((\sqrt 2)y)^2$.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much, funny thing is I did actually do that and then scribled it out! Thanks for the speedy response :-)

Comment: But, surely any number times root 2 wouldn't be an integer? So m and n wouldn't belong to integers?

Answer (score 0):

The expression can be rewrited as: $$(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy+x^2+y^2-2xy=2(x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: Thanks, but, just as a query, how did you reach that conclusion? (Surely you can't look at the question and know what steps to take, or is it practice?)

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity $\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(c^2+d^2\right)=\left(ac+bd\right)^2+\left(ad-bc\right)^2$, $2\left(x^2+y^2\right)=\left(1^2+1^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2\right)=\left(x+y\right)^2+\left(x-y\right)^2$